# PyQt5 How to update resource files after they've been compiled?

Tags: python, pyqt5

When I run my program, it displays a UI with many things on, some of those 'things' are images, that change depending on a user input. The input is recorded before the pyqt program is ran, and the images change using a different script, which also runs before the pyqt program. But for some reason the resource file doesnt care what the images look like, and only displays the images that were there when the resource file was compiled. Any tips? Just looking for some commands or something that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource files(.qrc) are used to place static files such as icons, sounds, videos, etc. These are converted into python code with the `pyrcc4` or `pyrcc5` command and are loaded into ram, so they can not be modified online. In the case of C++ they are loaded into the executable. In both cases they can not be modified.

Comment: ah well, I'll have to find a way around my problem, thanks anyway :)